# Python output is unwillingly stuck in for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop

I am trying to make a program that "talks" like a human (yes, I know, big dream).

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re
from speech import say as talk
from random import randint

yesnoquestion = ["do", "is", "can", "are", "would", "am"]
greetings = ["hi", "hello", "greetings"]

def say(phrase):
    print phrase
    talk(phrase)

def question():
    randominteger = randint(1,2)
    if words[0] in yesnoquestion and randominteger == 1:
        say("Yes.")
    elif words[0] in yesnoquestion and randominteger == 2:
        say("No.")
    elif "name" and "your" in words:
        say("I think I have already told you. My name is Eliza.")
    else:
        say("Just because. ")

def other():
    for listelement in words:
        if listelement in greetings:
            say("Nice to meet you. ")
        elif listelement == "name":
            indices = [i+2 for i, word in enumerate(words) if word == 'name']
            names = [words[i] for i in indices if i < len(words)]
            for usname in names:
                say("Hi, " + usname.title() + ".")
        else:
            say("I see. ")
say("Hi, my name is Eliza.")
words = []

while 1:
    text = raw_input("> ")
    words = map(lambda x:x.lower(), re.sub("[^\w]", " ",  text).split())
    #print words
    if text[-1] == "?":
        question()
    else:
        other()
```

The problem is that when I type in a sentence, not a question, the output is repeated as there are words in that sentence.

```
C:\Users\chef> python C:\Users\chef\Desktop\eliza.py
Hi, my name is Eliza.
> I love pizza.
I see.
I see.
I see.
> You seem to have encountered a bug.
I see.
I see.
I see.
I see.
I see.
I see.
I see.
>
```

How should I fix this? I am pretty sure this is caused by the for loop, but I have no idea how to.

Comment: What is   `words = map(lambda x:x.lower(), re.sub("[^\w]", " ",  text).split())`? supposed to be doing?

Comment: your program is doing exactly what you asked it to.  sentences will ALWAYS end up in the `else` block within the for loop because the first two conditions are not met.  
Start with writing your code in plain text - pseudo-code first so you fully understand what you are trying to achieve before writing a line of code.  This helps when you are beginning programming

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I'm putting all words in a list, and then get "useful" words and work with them.

Comment: @OkezieE thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are responding to every word in *words*. Add breaks after *say()* or proccess words another way.

```
for listelement in words:
    if listelement in greetings:
        say("Nice to meet you. ")
        break
    elif listelement == "name":
        indices = [i + 2 for i, word in enumerate(words) if word == 'name']
        names = [words[i] for i in indices if i < len(words)]
        for usname in names:
            say("Hi, " + usname.title() + ".")
            break    
    else:
        say("I see. ")
        break
```

Comment: Selected answer for simplicity. Why didn't I realize that I had to break from the for loop?

Comment: But this answer might fail if any greeting words used with the keyword "name".

Answer (score 0):

```
def other():
    for listelement in words:
        if listelement in greetings:
            say("Nice to meet you. ")
            return  # no need to continue with the loop
        elif listelement == "name":
            indices = [i+2 for i, word in enumerate(words) if word == 'name']
            names = [words[i] for i in indices if i < len(words)]
            for usname in names:
                say("Hi, " + usname.title() + ".")
            return  # no need to continue with the loop
    say("I see. ")  # there are no greetings and "name" is not among words
```

The problem with your code is that you didn't return from a function when you probably should have. Also you called 'say' function for every word that wasn't a "name" or wasn't among greetings. So it makes sense to move

```
say("I see. ")
```

outside of the loop.

UPDATE: A simple counterexample to master_Alish's answer: what if you have

```
words = ["My", "name", "is", "Bob"]
```

Then you will not greet him with

```
say("Hi, " + usname.title() + ".")
```

since you will fall through to 'else' part on the first iteration and return from the function, never reaching "name" element in a variable "words".

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense that "I love pizza" is print I see 3 times, because you are iterating over each word of the sentence 3 times, and for each word if it's not a greeting or a name, you print "I see".

You could try accumulating the your output sentences, and print them at the end:

```
type = None
all_names = []
for listelement in words:
    if listelement in greetings:
        type = 'greeting'
    elif listelement == "name":
        indices = [i+2 for i, word in enumerate(words) if word == 'name']
        names = [words[i] for i in indices if i < len(words)]
        all_names += names



if type == 'greeting':
    say("Nice to meet you. ")
elif type == 'names':
    for usname in names:
        say("Hi, " + usname.title() + ".")
else:
    say("I see. ")
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you intended was this.

Try it and return me with any questions.

The problem was your for loop going over all the words you splited and activate say() according to the number of words you entered.

```
def other():
    if any(word in greetings for word in words):
        say("Nice to meet you. ")
    elif "name" in words:
        indices = [i+2 for i, word in enumerate(words) if word == 'name']
        names = [words[i] for i in indices if i < len(words)]
        for usname in names:
            say("Hi, " + usname.title() + ".")
    else:
        say("I see. ")
```